# How can I do step-by-step calculations for the three equations to be equivalent to each other?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am working on logistic regression, and have faced with the three equations below. I am told they are all equivalent. Why, how can I do the step by step calculations for them to be equivalent?

1. $\dfrac{\Phi}{1-\Phi} = e^{(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \dots + \beta_kX_k)}$
2. $\Phi = \dfrac{e^{(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \dots + \beta_kX_k)}}{1 + e^{(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \dots + \beta_kX_k)}}$
3. $\Phi = \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \dots + \beta_kX_k)}}$

Comment: Isn't this just basic algebra?

Comment: Did you mean $e^{\beta_0 X_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \cdots \beta_k X_k}$? The way you have it, $X_2$ appears twice, and there is no $X_1$ or $X_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=e^{(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_2 + \beta_2X_2 + \cdots + \beta_kX_k)}$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{\Phi}{1-\Phi}&=y\tag1\\
\Phi&=y(1-\Phi)\\
\Phi&=y-y\,\Phi\\
\Phi+y\,\Phi&=y\\
\Phi(1+y)&=y\\
\Phi&=\frac{y}{1+y}.\tag2
\end{align}
Multiplying the numerator and denominator of RHS in $(2)$ by $\dfrac1y$ yields
\begin{align}
\Phi&=\frac{y}{1+y}\cdot\frac{\frac1y}{\frac1y}\\
&=\frac1{\frac1y+1}\\
&=\frac1{y^{-1}+1}.\tag3
\end{align}

Comment: Aren't you actually multiplying the right hand side of (2) by $1$ here?

Comment: @user139388 Yup, that's true. It's common thing in algebra manipulation.

Comment: I know, its just that you say you are multiplying by $\frac{1}{y}$ when in fact you are multiplying by $\frac{1/y}{1/y}$

Comment: @user139388 Is this OK now?

Comment: Yup! all is good :)

Answer (score 1):

Let y = $e^{\sum_{i=0}^k \beta_i X_i}$ with $X_0 \equiv 1$. Equation $1$ says
$$
  \frac{\Phi}{1 - \Phi}
= y.
$$
Thus
$$
  \frac{y}{1+y}
= \frac{\Phi/(1-\Phi)}{1 + \Phi/(1-\Phi)}
= \frac{\Phi}{(1-\Phi) + \Phi}
= \Phi,
$$
verifying equation $2$, and equation $3$ is true since
$$
  \frac{1}{1 + 1/y}
= \frac{y}{y+1}
$$
which, from above, is again equal to $\Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Start by rewriting it as
$$
\frac{\Phi}{1 - \Phi} = e^B
$$
$$
\Phi = \frac{e^B}{1 + e^B}
$$
$$
\Phi = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-B}}
$$
and then the substitution is simpler to write, even though it is the same thing--just multiply by $e^B$ in the bottom one, for example.

It is always a good idea to simplify notation for any algebraic expression whenever possible.  This makes the problem look less intimidating.